# Help finding a very interesting book about alien invasion, please

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

In the 1990s, I checked out a book from my local library about an alien invasion. I think it was misfiled, because it was in the non-fiction section.

The book was designed in such as a way to make it look like a classified document that was transcribed. There were markings like "eyes only" and "classified" on it.Full of diagrams and black and white drawings, and fake military looking insignias.

In the book, several alien species were described.

The main bad guys were known as "The Blight", who were small creatures led by a queen. They had a weapon called a "Skeletal Disintegrator". They were supposedly susceptible to bacteria, demanded extreme cleanliness, and were very weak against high volume or intense sound waves. In the end, they were defeated by using a radio telescope to beam sound waves toward their fleet - and the technician in control accidentally inputted the late show or something instead of the intense sound developed by scientists, but it worked anyway.

They also controlled alien spies called the "Aerie" which were just like classical fairies, and they were a subjugated race.

During the tour of space described by the narrator, they flew past a steampunk ship piloted by the "Body Electric" race. The narrator also flew past the planet - get this - "V-8" inhabited by "mobile vegetable lifeforms". These two things were illustrated.

Thats all I can remember, It was was early 90s. It was very absurd, but id still like to find a copy!

Thanks if you can help me, and everyone have a good day!

Comment: Interesting. Using the keywords pulls up a lot of crackpot UFO sites, but so far no mention of a book.

Comment: If you know which library it was, could you try asking there?

Comment: the mobile vegetable life forms called V-8 makes me wanna say Terry Pratchett

Comment: @SeanDuggan it also doesn't help that the Aerie is a race of aliens in the Marvel Universe, though clearly not the same.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield
{nods} And the White Wolf Exalted universe has The Blight and a group called the Priests of the Body Electric.

Comment: Thanks for the leads, but this book was not part of a series. I've tried looking at that library, but the only records of checkout they have is for books never returned and are owed charges, and it is not on the self anywhere. Years ago I found mention of it on a book forum, but I can't find that entry either. @seanduggan, thats an interesting lead, it may be coincidence, but you know how things get built upon in a creative mind! What is most interesting to me, is that this book was in the non-fiction section....it was either misfiled by staff, or actually classified as non-fiction somehow.

Comment: Found it - slept on it a bit and remembered a few details....it was written as a REPORT!        http://www.amazon.com/The-Extraterrestrial-Report-Richard-Siegel/dp/0891040935

Comment: @PhasedOut: Congrats! Go ahead and post it as an answer at the bottom. Perfectly valid to answer your own question, after all. You will have a delay of something like 2 days before you can "accept" it, but it will be helpful for those in the future.

Answer (score 7):

Per the asker's comment above, this title is *The Extraterrestrial Report* by Richard Siegel, published 1978.

[image: The Extraterrestrial Report - book cover]

From [a review on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/RSQQC3JLQ36AT/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=0891040935):

> This supposed "report" about alien contact begining in the 40's and coming to a head in the late 70's is more farce than fiction. Instead of using the tried and true method of writing an SF novel, Siegel and Butterfield, along with designer Jean-Claude Suares, put together something that looked real enough to make you think twice at first glance. Upon closer reading, however, you notice the little touches that only the Sf fan could provide - a reference by then President Carter (in a faked memo) to someone beating the Wildfire team at flag football or the visiting aliens wanting to take TV personality Robby the Robot back to their home planet. A curiousity at best but hard to find intact as most of the trade paberbacks from the period have bad glue that has gone brittle and pages fall out all over the place. Worth a look if you can find one.